# College chem study question, any help?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The molar extinction coefficient of reduced NADH (nicotinamide adenine dinucleotide phosphophate) at 340nm is 6220 L/mole·cm. 11ml of solution containing 0.8 micromoles of NADH were placed in a cuvette of 1.6cm light path. Calculate the percentage light transmission of this sample at 340nm